# Unlimited keepalive in MQTT

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

Currently developing something like "smart home" and I have few different devices in my home. All of them connected to `OpenHab` via `MQTT`. I'm using `Paho MQTT library` (Python) for my purposes.

Generally, MQTT has "keepalive" property. This property describes how much time my client will be connected (AFAIK it sends the ping to the server) to MQTT server when there are no updates on the subscribed topic.

But here I have a huge problem. Needed topic could be updated once per hour or even once per few days/months. Let's say that this is indoor alarm.
How can I avoid that keepalive timeout or ignore that field? Could it be unlimited?

Comment: https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-10-alive-client-take-over/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have miss understood what the `keepalive` value represents.

MQTT clients can stay connected indefinitely even if they do not publish or receive any messages. But the broker needs to keep track of which clients are still connected so it knows when to send the Last Will and Testament (LWT) message for the client. In order to do this it uses the `keepalive` time.

Every time a message is sent or received by the client, the broker resets a timer, if this timer exceeds 1.5 times the value of the `keepalive` time then the broker marks the client as disconnected and processes the LWT. To prevent clients with very low messages rates from being disconnected, such a client can send a `PINGREQ` packet at any time (most likely on timeout of the `keepalive` value) to the server/broker. The server receives the `PINGREQ`, answers with a `PINGRESP` packet and it will reset the `keepalive` timer to zero and leave the client in the connected state.

See Keep Alive section of the MQTT standard: (http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc385349238)

> The Client can send PINGREQ at any time, irrespective of the Keep Alive value, and use the PINGRESP to determine that the network and the Server are working. If the Keep Alive value is non-zero and the Server does not receive a Control Packet from the Client within one and a half times the Keep Alive time period, it MUST disconnect the Network Connection to the Client as if the network had failed

Comment: then how does the keep alive use? I still don't know how does keep alive use, when client can send ping anytime to broker

Comment: There point of the keepsake punch is for when the client is not sending messages

Comment: how many interval it reasonable for mobile chat app? too long might lost, too short, consume many battery life.

Comment: @NicholasJela ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

When sending the initial MQTT CONNECT message from a client, you can supply an optional "keep-alive" value. This value is a time interval, measured in seconds, during which the broker expects a client to send a message, such as a PUBLISH message. If no message is sent from the client to the broker during the interval, the broker automatically closes the connection. Note that the keep-alive value you specify is multiplied by 1.5, so setting a 10-minute keep-alive actually results in a 15 minute interval.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `Keep Alive` section of the [MQTT specification](https://mqtt.org/mqtt-specification/):

> A Keep Alive **value of 0** has the effect of turning off the Keep Alive mechanism. If Keep Alive is 0 the Client is not obliged to send MQTT Control Packets on any particular schedule. [v5 spec source](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/mqtt-v5.0.html)

Therefore, set the keep alive to 0, and then the client doesn't have to send a keep alive signal as often. The server should respect that this connection with a client (e.g. from last year) should still be connected, but it won't be guaranteed (The client might be disconnected when the server is shut down).